# Flask server hangs with specific url parameter values

Tags: python, flask

My flask server just takes a snapshot of the URL that is provided in the get request like so

```
localhost:5555/shot/http://rainbow.com
```

it returns the screenshot as expected.

However, when I input another url, the whole server no longer responds to any further requests. When I check the server output, nothing, not even the GET request is displayed.

```
localhost:5555/shot/http://somesite.com/page/Acampo;_ylt=AjIcXmaV0CCq0hoTawYKqOOeNcIF;_ylv=3
```

This is a serious problem, why does this happen and how can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to analyze the logs, and if the logs don't say anything, you need to add more logging so that it does. There is no way we are able to determine what part of your code and/or server configuration (all of which you have not provided) is causing the problem.

Comment: gotcha...I will investigate this mroe